# struggling with string characters

Tags: python

I am trying to solve an exercise regarding strings in Python. The exercise says: Write a function that takes a string word and returns a list of strings containing the sound elements of the given word.

A sound element is a maximal sequence of 1 or more consonants followed by 1 or more vowels. In other words, i am supposed to iterate over a string of characters and split it everytime a vowel is followed by a consonant.

Example:

the following string given in input:

```
S = 'unconditionally'
```

should return the following list

```
L = ['u','nco','ndi','tio','na','lly']
```

In order to solve the exercise, i have written the following function:

```
def split_words(S): 
    string = ''
    syllables = []
    vowels = ['a','e','i','o','u','j','y']
    for i in range(len(S)):
        if S[i] not in vowels:
            string += S[i]
        elif S[i] in vowels and S[i+1] not in vowels:
                string += S[i]
                syllables.append(string)
                string = ''
    return syllables
```

Which should be able to solve it. The problem is that i get an index-out-of-range error everytime i run the program. I know the issue is in the elif statement which i don't know how to get rid of.

Is there any way to solve this exercise without importing any external libraries?

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: `S[i+1]` is going to index one extra value past the end of the list `S` once `i` reaches the last index of the list. That's your issue. You need to first make sure you're not at the very end of the list before checking at that index.

Comment: Yes i know. In fact, i tried using S[i-1] but i don't get to solve it

Comment: Okay then you should've mentioned that in your post, since now you have one comment and one answer pointing it out, meaning we've both wasted our time since you didn't include info that you already knew.

Comment: Not best but simple: Append an "x" to S initially and let i iterate over "range(len(S) - 1)".

Comment: @RandomDavis I know. I am sorry

Answer (score 2):

You iterate till the index of the last character :

```
for i in range(len(S)):
```

and you have this line:

```
elif S[i] in vowels and S[i+1] not in vowels:
```

if `i` is the last index of `S`, then it will throw error on `S[i+1]`

Edit: You can use this:

```
def split_words(S): 
    string = ''
    syllables = []
    vowels = ['a','e','i','o','u','j','y']
    for i in range(len(S)):
        
        if S[i] not in vowels:
            if len(string) == 0 or not string[-1] in vowels: #here I check if length of string is 0 
#in this case I can append letter to it. And also if last letter (`string[-1]`) isn't a vowel,
#then also I can add this letter to string 
                string += S[i]
            else: # if last letter was vowel then we reset string.
                syllables.append(string)
                string = ''
                string += S[i]

        else: 
                string += S[i]
    syllables.append(string)
    return syllables
```

We can further simplify code, because we have `string += S[i]` in every block of if-else:

```
def split_words(S): 
    string = ''
    syllables = []
    vowels = ['a','e','i','o','u','j','y']
    for i in range(len(S)):
        
        if S[i] not in vowels and len(string) > 0 and string[-1] in vowels:
            syllables.append(string)
            string = ''
        string += S[i] 
     syllables.append(string)           
    return syllables
```

Comment: There are too many ways to solve this. Do you want me to write any of them?

Comment: @alex108, I haven't heard from you in a while

Comment: I know it sounds rude, but I think I deserve acceptance from your side.